# Array left rotation in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of integers and a number, I need to perform left rotations on the array and return the updated array to be printed as a single line of space-separated integers.
I pass 7/9 checks, but some with large arrays fail because of time-out.

**The time has to be <= 4 sec.**

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
       int x = 0;
       while (x != d) {
           int first = a[0];
           int last = a[a.length - 1];
           for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
               a[i] = a[i + 1];
               if (i == a.length - 2)
                   a[a.length - 2] = last;
               a[a.length - 1] = first;
           }
           x++;
       }
       return a;
   }
```

Comment: `java.util.Collections.rotate2` looks like a sensible algorithm http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/5bc878966264/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java

Answer (score 2):

you're rotating only one position at a time, it is very slow, it is better to shift elements to appropriate places, for example:

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    if (d == 0 || a == null || a.length == 0) {
        return a;
    }

    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = a[(i + d) % a.length];
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line? 
`b[i] = a[(i + d) % a.length];`

Comment: @JJKam it takes element from old array and shifts it into new array, as soon as `i+d` can be beyond array length, it has `%` to wrap around it

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you could apply to this problem to improve the runtime.

1. Ensure that `d` is less than `a.length`. If `d` is greater than `a.length`, then you are rotating elements past their original position and wasting cycles. An easy way to achieve this is with the modulus assignment operator (i.e., `d %= a.length`, which is equivalent to `d = d % a.length`).
2. Elements should be shifted by the whole distance we are rotating, rather than shifting by one space each time. This allows us to perform the entire operation is 1 action, instead of in `d` action(s).

Applying these two principles would give us the following code:

```java
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
  if (d < 0) {
    d = a.length - (-d % a.length);
  }

  d %= a.length;

  if (d == 0) {
    return a;
  }

  int first = a[0];

  int i = 0;
  int position = 0;

  while (i < a.length) {
    a[position] = a[(position + d) % a.length];

    position = (position + d) % a.length;
    i++;
  }

  a[a.length - d] = first;

  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the rotations one by one. If you rotate by `d`, the element at index `i` moves to index `i - d` when `i >= d`, and into index `N + i - d` when `i < d`. Makes sense?

```
int[] result = new int[a.length]
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (i < d) {
        result[a.length + i - d] = a[i];
    } else {
        result[i - d] = a[i];
    }
}
return result;
```

To handle the case where d >= a.length, you can add `d = d % a.length` as a pre-processing step.

Comment: This is very succinct and accurate. What do you imply by "rotations one by one"?
Aren't you doing the same?

Comment: Your first implementation computes "d" full rotations of the array, one by one.

Comment: How did you manage to avoid getting an exception? E.g. if a.length=3, i=0 and d=9?
The result would be -6. My tests are passed, but I don't know how did you escape it?

Comment: ah, that case is not covered... Most likely your tests don't exercise that case.

Answer (score 0):

You make multiple passes, each time rotating by one place, which makes your program slow.
There are at least 3 approaches to improve your program:

- allocate a new array and put elements in appropriate locations, instead of rotating in place
- use a buffer to store d elements while rotating others in place
- use a juggling algorithm https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/amp/

The third option performs rotation in place.

It may be worthwhile to microbenchmark all 3 to compare the speed for different input sizes

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can repeat the rotation `d` times as you did in your sample code. But much faster would be if you would calculate the shift and do it in one go:

import static java.lang.System.*;

```
static int[] rotLeft( int[] a, int d ) 
{
    var len = a.length;
    var shift = d % len;
    var buffer = new int[len]; 
    arraycopy( a, shift, buffer, 0, len - shift );
    arraycopy( a, 0, buffer, len - shift, shift );
    arraycopy( buffer, 0, a, 0, len );
    return a;
}
```

Of course, instead of `System.arraycopy()` you can use a `for`-loop. If you are not forced to return `a`, you can omit the third call to `arraycopy()` and return `buffer` instead; this would leave the original array unchanged, too.

To output the array, try this:

```
var joiner = new StringJoiner( " " );
for( var v : a ) joiner.add( Integer.toString( v ) );
System.out.println( joiner.toString() );
```

Comment: 1) Your buffer is bigger than needed, it only needs to be `shift`, not `len`. See e.g. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60877790/5221149). --- 2) If you expect oversized values of `d`, why not expect negative values too?

Comment: @Andreas: negative numbers would be a right shift, but there are no "oversized numbers" in the specification: it says "left-rotate `d` times". The term `d % a.length` is just an optimisation. And regarding the buffer: why should I return the input array after it was modified in-place? Either the method returns `void`, or it should return buffer – but finally, I was lazy. But if really an in-place rotation is required, you are right, a buffer of size `shift` would do the job.

Comment: 1) `d % a.length` is not an optimization, not for this answer's code. It is a requirement to prevent `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `d > a.length`. --- 2) *"why should I return the input array"* But you are doing that. *"it should return buffer"* But you're not doing that. And since you *are* copying all of `buffer` back to `a`, to return it, the buffer is bigger than it needs to be, because the second `arraycopy` could be in-place in `a`, which is what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, you should use the built-in array copy methods.

If you have to update the existing array, like your code is doing, I'd recommend doing it like this:

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    if (a == null || a.length <= 1)
        return a; // nothing to rotate
    int shift = (d % a.length + a.length) % a.length; // normalize d
    if (shift == 0)
        return a; // no or full rotation(s)
    int[] t = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, shift);
    System.arraycopy(a, shift, a, 0, a.length - shift);
    System.arraycopy(t, 0, a, a.length - shift, shift);
    return a;
}
```

If the returned array must be different, like this other answers do, I'd do it like this:

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    if (a == null || a.length <= 1)
        return Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length); // nothing to rotate
    int shift = (d % a.length + a.length) % a.length; // normalize d
    if (shift == 0)
        return Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length); // no or full rotation(s)
    int[] t = new int[a.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, shift, t, 0, a.length - shift);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, t, a.length - shift, shift);
    return t;
}
```

Both of the above solution allow `d` to exceed the size of the array, i.e. do more than a full rotation, and to use negative values, i.e. rotate right instead of left.

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotLeft(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 1)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotLeft(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 3)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotLeft(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotLeft(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 7)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotLeft(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, -7)));
```

*Output*

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```